# Login Form not working

Tags: magento-1.9, login

I am trying to display Login form in a pop-up window on a home page. 
I am displaying pop-up using Fancybox2. That is working fine.

To display Login Form, I have used

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('customer/form/mini.login.phtml')->toHtml();
                        ?>
```

this code.
Above code is displaying Login Form. But when I enter correct or wrong details, it redirects to `my-domain/index.php/customer/account/login/` page. On that page also I have displayed Login as well as register forms . On this page also Login Form doesn't work. It redirects to the same page.

For registration form, I have used

`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_register')->setTemplate('customer/form/register.phtml')->toHtml();`

this code and It is working fine.

Below is the code from **template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml** :

```
<div id="login_checkout" class="checkout-login">
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="login_tabs">
            <li><a href="#" class="current"><?php echo $this->__('Log in') ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up') ?></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="panes_login">
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
                    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" placeholder="Email Address" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" placeholder="Password" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="forgat-pass">
                            <div class="stay_signin">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="stay_signin"><label for="stay_signin">Stay signed in</label>
                            </div>
                            <!--<a href="#forget_pass_popup" class="forget_pass_popup f-left">I forgot my password</a>-->
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left forgot-password forget_pass_popup"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>
                        </div>
                </form>

                        <div class="social-login">
                              <div class="or"><span>Or</span></div>
                              <p>Sign in with</p>
                              <!--<a class="google-login" href="#">Google</a>
                              <a class="facebook-login" href="#">Facebook</a>-->
                              <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_socialconnect/google_button')->setTemplate('inchoo/socialconnect/google/button.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
                              <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_socialconnect/facebook_button')->setTemplate('inchoo/socialconnect/facebook/button.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
                            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer_form_register'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your mini.login.phtml file inside `<form>` tag

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Comment: <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> This is already present in the login.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I will help you. One more things while adding form key.

```
   <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

check whether you are pasting in same login.phtml that are used in frontend. sometimes in xampp also have cache issue.

For That

```
app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

/* to solve login issue */
  /*if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
  unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
  if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
  unset($cookieParams['secure']);
  if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
  unset($cookieParams['domain']);
  }
  }
  }

if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
  $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();*/ //I have commented these lines
```

or

Open your Magento installation directory. Locate and open index.php file.

Search for error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); code.

Comment it out like that: /*error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);*/

And use the following code instead:

error_reporting(E_ALL); $_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;

Uncomment it by removing the # sign, so it looks like that:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Save this file and upload to the server. Reload your website page to see errors.

==========alternative==================

change localhost to 127.0.0.1
paste your error if you can see.